# SECRET_KEY settings not empty but returning empty on Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

I just installed [wagtail-blog](https://pypi.org/project/wagtail-blog/) on my project and added *blog* to the INSTALLED_APPS and `url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace="blog")),` to the main `urls.py`. Once I migrated, it returned `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.`

I double checked my `base.py` and it has a string on the SECRET_KEY but is still returning the error. Here's the MIDDLEWARE and INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'global',
'wagtail.contrib.forms',
'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
'wagtail.embeds',
'wagtail.sites',
'wagtail.users',
'wagtail.snippets',
'wagtail.documents',
'wagtail.images',
'wagtail.search',
'wagtail.admin',
'wagtail.core',
'wagtail.contrib.styleguide',
'modelcluster',
'taggit',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'bootstrap3',
'copyright',
'landing',
'registration',
'blog',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'wagtail.core.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: Is your virtual env activated? Do you explicitly call a settings file?If you see the error, run a pip freeze to confirm Django is installed.

Comment: @dfundako I use pip-compile and pip-sync

Comment: Don't know what that means. Either way, confirm Django is installed in the environment that you are trying to run your management command from.

Comment: it's pip tools. so I need to run an env even on pip tools?

Comment: @dfundako I ran everything on the env but still got the same error

Answer (score 1):

It turned out I had to run pip install -r requirements.txt to fix the problem.